Proof for associativity of a modified "matrix multiplication"
I'm trying to prove the associativity of a modified form of matrix multiplication (which is defined below) and I found the following proof which I'm confused about:
For matrices $W_i, W_j, W_p$, to verify associativity, we need to check that
$$(W_i W_j) W_p = W_i (W_j W_p)$$
for all $i$, $j$, and $p$, consider entry $(a,b)$ of the left-hand side. This is:
$$= \min_{1 \leq k \leq n}((W_i W_j)_{a,k} + W_{k,b}^p)$$
$$= \min_{1 \leq k \leq n} (\min_{1 \leq q \leq n} (W_{a,q}^i + W_{q,k}^j) + W_{k,b}^p)$$
$$= \min_{1 \leq q \leq n} (W_{a,q}^i + \min_{1 \leq k \leq n} (W_{q,k}^j + W_{k,b}^p))$$
$$= \min_{1 \leq q \leq n} (W_{a,q}^i + (W_j W_p)_{q,b})$$
which is precisely entry $(a,b)$ of the right-hand side.
How does this step follow:
$$\min_{1 \leq k \leq n} (\min_{1 \leq q \leq n} (W_{a,q}^i + W_{q,k}^j) + W_{k,b}^p) = \min_{1 \leq q \leq n} (W_{a,q}^i + \min_{1 \leq k \leq n} (W_{q,k}^j + W_{k,b}^p))$$

I do not understand your notation but it looks like you are using the "tropical semifield" to define the modified matrix multiplication, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_geometry#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20tropical%20geometry%20is,A%20tropical%20cubic%20curve

This is a question from an Algorithms book and the proof uses the same notation as the book. In the book, they don't explicitly mention the "tropical semifield", but after following the link you provided, it does seem like that is what they are referring to

You did not defined the "modified matrix product." Given what you wrote, here, what I think, is the definition. First, define the tropical semiring structure on $\mathbb R$ with tropical binary operations $\oplus$ and $\otimes$ defined by:

$x \oplus y= \min(x,y)$.

$x\otimes y= x+y$.


It is an easy exercise to verify that both tropical binary operations are commutative and associative, and satisfy the distributive law:
$$
x\otimes (y\oplus z)= (x\otimes y) \oplus (x\otimes z), 
$$
$$
(x\oplus y)\otimes z= (x\otimes z)\oplus (y\otimes z).
$$
This allows one to eliminate brackets when applying tropical addition and multiplication inductively and define
$$
\sum^{\oplus}_{i\ge 1} x_i= (...(x_1\oplus x_2)\oplus x_3)...) 
$$
Now, we are ready to define the tropical product of matrices (which you call the "modified matrix product"): For matrices $A=(a_{ij})$ and $B=(b_{jk})$ define the matrix $C=A\boxtimes B$ by the formula familiar from Linear Algebra:
$$
C=(c_{ik}), \ c_{ik}= \sum^{\oplus}_j a_{ij}\otimes b_{jk}. 
$$
Since tropical binary operations satisfy the associative and distributive laws, the usual proof of associativity of matrix multiplication goes through and we get:
$$
(A\boxtimes B)\boxtimes C= A\boxtimes (B\boxtimes C)\ \ \  \ \ \ (*).
$$
The proof is completely formal. The matrix coefficients of the left hand-side of $(*)$ are:
$$
\sum^\oplus_k (\sum^\oplus_j a_{ij}\otimes b_{jk}) \otimes c_{kl}).
$$
Applying the distributive and associative laws, we get:
$$
\sum^\oplus_k \sum^\oplus_j a_{ij}\otimes b_{jk} \otimes c_{kl}
$$
For the right hand-side  of $(*)$ we get:
$$
\sum^\oplus_j   a_{ij} \otimes (\sum^\oplus_k b_{jk}\otimes c_{kl}).  $$
Again, applying the distributive and associative laws, we obtain:
$$
\sum^\oplus_j \sum^\oplus_k a_{ij} \otimes  b_{jk}\otimes c_{kl}.  $$
Rearranging the order of tropical summation (which uses associativity and commutativity of the tropical summation), we obtain  the equality of the left hand-side and the right hand-side  of $(*)$.
Similarly, one also gets
$$
(A\boxplus B)\boxtimes C= A\boxtimes C \boxplus B\boxtimes C,
$$
where $A\boxplus B$ is defined using $\oplus$ with the usual component-wise tropical addition of matrix entries.
